# Python data manipulation for a particular data set

Tags: python

I encountered this sub problem while solving a bigger problem.

I have a table like this:

```
start end   

313  516
517  1878
1879 2155
3649 3669
3670 5024
5034 6968
```

My output should be :

```
313  2155
3649 5024
5034 6968
```

you get this output by merging consecutive data sets , i.e , here 1878 and 1879 are consecutive and so on.

I tried to do it like this

```
i = 0
if start[i+1] == end[i]+1 :
    table.append(start[i],end[i+1])
```

this prints :

```
313 1878
517 2155
```

and so on...

As expected , it works for 1 row level . I want to make it work for any row level.

Comment: Your code snippet works, just wrap it in a function and pass the `i` param as an arg... [simples](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTSCUYcp20A)

Comment: @EdChum No, it's more complex than that.

Comment: @Duncan it was less complex initially.. seems to have fleshed out more since I last looked at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
def consolidate(start, end):
    _start = start[:]                # Make a copy since we're modifying the list
    result = []
    for i in range(len(_start)-1):   # Iterate until the second-to-last pair
        if _start[i+1] == end[i]+1:  # If two pairs are contiguous,
            _start[i+1] = _start[i]  # replace the start value with the previous one
        else:                                  # Otherwise
            result.append((_start[i], end[i])) # add the current pair to the result
    result.append((_start[i+1], end[i+1]))     # Don't forget the ultimate pair
    return result
```

Result:

```
>>> start = [313,517,1879,3649,3670,5034,6969]
>>> end = [516,1878,2155,3669,5024,6968,7000]
>>> consolidate(start,end)
[(313, 2155), (3649, 5024), (5034, 7000)]
```

Answer (score 2):

That's perfect for a [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) job:

```
def squash(lsts, el):
    if not lsts:
        return [list(el)]
    if lsts[-1][1] == el[0] - 1:
        lsts[-1][1] = el[1]
    else:
        lsts.append(list(el))
    return lsts

print reduce(squash, zip(start, end), [])
```

*Output*

```
[[313, 2155], [3649, 5024], [5034, 6968]]
```

Comment: +1 That's horrendously elegant. I use "horrendous" because I'm still grokking quite how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over both lists:

```
def func(start, end):
    result = []
    first = start[0]

    for i, j in zip(start[1:], end):
        if i == j + 1:
           continue
        result.append((first, j))
        first = i

    result.append((first, end[-1]))
    return result
```

Execution example:

```
In [73]: start = [313, 517, 1879, 3649, 3670, 5034, 6969]

In [74]: end = [516, 1878, 2155, 3669, 5024, 6968, 7000]

In [75]: func(start, end)
Out[75]: [(313, 2155), (3649, 5024), (5034, 7000)]
```